# Phillips–Perron test - Minus values interpretation

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I was using ur.pp function for running Phillips–Perron test for a timeseries data set and got following results.

```
Value of test-statistic, type: Z-tau  is: -3.0652 

         aux. Z statistics
Z-tau-mu            3.1097

Critical values for Z statistics: 
                     1pct      5pct     10pct
critical values -3.438771 -2.864502 -2.568362
```

As it is given, test statistics is -3.0652. 
Can I reject null hypothesis at 5% level? 
It seems that, in absolute term,3.0652>2.864502 (5% level value) and can reject null hypothesis. Am I getting it right? bit confused with minus values in test statistics and critical values.
Thank you.